# Getting data from .csv file into array list of objects

Tags: java, arrays, csv, object, arraylist

Here is the format of the .csv file I am working with -

```
Hostname,IP Address,Patched?,OS Version,Notes
A.example.COM,1.1.1.1,NO,11,Faulty fans
b.example.com,1.1.1.2,no,13,Behind the other routers so no one sees it
C.EXAMPLE.COM,1.1.1.3,no,12.1   
d.example.com,1.1.1.4,yes,14    
c.example.com,1.1.1.5,no,12,Case a bit loose
e.example.com,1.1.1.6,no,12.3   
f.example.com,1.1.1.7,No,15,Guarded by sharks with lasers on their heads
```

I currently have this program which reads in all data from the above .csv file into an array list before then outputting the results to the console as you can see in the included output text. Ideally I eventually need to be able to compare each different field in each different row with one another, perform calculations etc. so would like to save each row as an object inside an array list instead. I have tried doing this but so far with no success. Is there a simple way of modifying my program to do this? Also, if possible, I would like for the headings and the notes not to be included. Here is my code so far -

```
package crunchify;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CrunchifyCSVtoArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader crunchifyBuffer = null;

        try {
            String crunchifyLine;
            crunchifyBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Crunchify-CSV-to-ArrayList.csv"));

            while ((crunchifyLine = crunchifyBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("ArrayList data: " + crunchifyCSVtoArrayList(crunchifyLine) + "\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (crunchifyBuffer != null) crunchifyBuffer.close();
            } catch (IOException crunchifyException) {
                crunchifyException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // Utility which converts CSV to ArrayList using Split Operation
    public static ArrayList<String> crunchifyCSVtoArrayList(String crunchifyCSV) {
        ArrayList<String> crunchifyResult = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (crunchifyCSV != null) {
            String[] splitData = crunchifyCSV.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
                if (!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() == 0)) {
                    crunchifyResult.add(splitData[i].trim());
                }
            }
        }
        return crunchifyResult;
    }
}
```

Current output:

ArrayList data: [Hostname, IP Address, Patched?, OS Version, Notes]

ArrayList data: [A.example.COM, 1.1.1.1, NO, 11, Faulty fans]

ArrayList data: [b.example.com, 1.1.1.2, no, 13, Behind the other routers so no one sees it]

ArrayList data: [C.EXAMPLE.COM, 1.1.1.3, no, 12.1]

ArrayList data: [d.example.com, 1.1.1.4, yes, 14]

ArrayList data: [c.example.com, 1.1.1.5, no, 12, Case a bit loose]

ArrayList data: [e.example.com, 1.1.1.6, no, 12.3]

ArrayList data: [f.example.com, 1.1.1.7, No, 12.2]

ArrayList data: [g.example.com, 1.1.1.6, no, 15, Guarded by sharks with lasers on their heads]

To give some more detail on the kind of thing I will eventually need to do, it needs to print out which routers need updating e.g. if any of the routers are below version 12 then print that those ones need updating.

Comment: Instead of taking a screenshot of the code, it's better to copy the code here.

Comment: copy your code here, copy your output here, print expected output, describe your problem more clearly

Comment: you want to convert you row to object?

Comment: Yes fanshaoer I would like to have each row as a separate object

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom class to hold the data. Objects of this class represent a single row from the csv file.